# How to convert a gem to plugin in ruby on rails and vice versa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there any tool to convert plugin to gem and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Jeweler](http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) -- it helps you get all the files together that you need to build a gem, then have a look at [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org) to publish it when you're ready.

I would encourage you to build gems as opposed to plugins, they're typically easier to maintain during a project lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of a tangent, but you can vendor a gem into your application - meaning that you have a copy of the gem code in your /vendor/gems directory. All baked into the Rake tasks that ship with Rails.

Almost but not quite entirely unlike converting a gem to a plugin ...